# how to remove a folder from tracking in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

To ignore **./node_modules/** folder and **.idea** folder into .hgignore file so that I don't want to track them.

Currently I have the following rules on my .hgignore file.

```
*.orig
*./node_module/
*.idea/ 
*.rej
*~
*.o
tests/*.err
```

But abort error on `hg status`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i found tip . here is how to .
Foradding **node_modules/** and **.idea/** folder you need to specify the following.**N.B > is refers terminal.**

> touch .hgignore 
>   nano .hgignore

add the following

```
^node_modules/
^.idea/
```

Done !

Comment: how would this be if node_modules is not in the root?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `hg help hgignore` points to have a look at `hg help patterns`. I can't quite explain it better:

```
Mercurial accepts several notations for identifying one or more files at a
time.

By default, Mercurial treats filenames as shell-style extended glob
patterns.

Alternate pattern notations must be specified explicitly.

Note:
  Patterns specified in ".hgignore" are not rooted. Please see 'hg help
  hgignore' for details.

To use a plain path name without any pattern matching, start it with
"path:". These path names must completely match starting at the current
repository root.

To use an extended glob, start a name with "glob:". Globs are rooted at
the current directory; a glob such as "*.c" will only match files in the
current directory ending with ".c".

The supported glob syntax extensions are "**" to match any string across
path separators and "{a,b}" to mean "a or b".
```

(...)

```
Plain examples:

  path:foo/bar   a name bar in a directory named foo in the root
                 of the repository
  path:path:name a file or directory named "path:name"
```

There are alternate ways to specify paths using regex as well as also explained in the available command line help.

So, use something like

```
node_module/**
.idea/**
```

or

```
path:node_module
path:.idea
```

provided you quoted your entire .hgignore and thus use the default glob pattern matching.